# Can not find module webpage using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, discord

I am using PhantomJS to search for words on a web page, I tried to set it up like:

```
const phantomjs = require("phantomjs-prebuilt");

if (cmd === `${prefix}check`) {
    let word = (args[0]);
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.open('https://discordapp.com/channels/000/000', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (data.indexOf(word) >= 0) {
            message.reply(word+ ' Found!');
        } else {
            message.reply(word+ ' Not found.');
        }
    });
}
```

However I'm getting the following error:

> (node:3520) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find
>   module 'webpage'

What is causing this?

**Edit**
I just saw that it does not work with Node JS, is it possible to call the seperate JS file and pass the `(args[0]);`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use PhantomJS from node.js, you can, there are several packages for that, one of them is [phantom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom). It supports Promises and async/await functions:

```
const phantom = require('phantom');

(async function() {
  const instance = await phantom.create();
  const page = await instance.createPage();
  await page.on('onResourceRequested', function(requestData) {
    console.info('Requesting', requestData.url);
  });

  const status = await page.open('https://stackoverflow.com/');
  const content = await page.property('content');
  console.log(content);

  await instance.exit();
})();
```

---

You can of course just launch PhantomJS from command-line and pass necessary arguments to it:

```
phantomjs script.js https://stackoverflow.com
```

and then recieve them in the script with [system.args](http://phantomjs.org/api/system/property/args.html)

```
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;

if (args.length === 1) {
  console.log('Try to pass some arguments when invoking this script!');
} else {
  args.forEach(function(arg, i) {
    console.log(i + ': ' + arg);
  });
}
```

---

Please note that you're using `page.open` wrong, there's no `data` var in callback function signature. If you want to get all of a page's contents, refer to [page.content](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/content.html) variable:

```
page.open('http://phantomjs.org', function (status) {
  var content = page.content;
  console.log('Content: ' + content);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: The request returns the HTML of the page but you can only see the content when signed in into Discord for example, would it be possible to pass credentials?

Comment: You'd need to login into that app first, that is of course possible.

Comment: How could I pass credentials?

Comment: Loggin in with PhantomJS is another issue completely. If you wish you can create another question, but isn't it better to try to figure it out yourself? You could search for [How to log in with phantomjs](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+log+in+with+phantomjs&oq=how+to+log+in+with+phantomjs)